# Vaadin 24 PDF Resource in new Tab

Tags: pdf, tabs, vaadin

I am creating a JasperReport with the Libery.

How do I manage to display this resource in a new tab?

Patrick

my current code

```
LocalDateTime lt = LocalDateTime .now();
final StreamResource resource = new StreamResource("finance_"+  lt + ".pdf",
               () -> new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfOutputStream.toByteArray()));
final StreamRegistration registration = VaadinSession.getCurrent().getResourceRegistry().registerResource(resource);
UI.getCurrent().getPage().setLocation(registration.getResourceUri());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to download the PDF via `Anchor`

```java
LocalDateTime lt = LocalDateTime .now();
StreamResource resource = new StreamResource("finance_"+  lt + ".pdf",
       () -> new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfOutputStream.toByteArray()));

Anchor anchor = new Anchor(resource, "Download  PDF");
anchor.getElement().setAttribute("download", true);
```

You can also make the link invisible, create a Button and click the Anchor programamtically.

```java
Button button = new Button("Download");
button.addClickListener(event -> {
    anchor.getElement().callJsFunction("click");
    dialog.close();
});
```